# Finding the largest number in each column in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi guys I wan to build a program with external variable but I have difficulties in displaying the number out when the program is debug.My program is to display the largest number in each column when the time is selected for each column.For example selected 1.00 and the largest number is 98.

First Source File

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    extern int transitTime[];
    extern float time[];
    int i;
    int number,largest;
    printf("Please enter the time leaving TP.\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    largest=time[number-1];
    for(i=number-1;i<11*4;i+11)
    {
    if(number>largest)largest=number;
    }
    printf("Largest=%d\n",largest);
}
```

Second Source File

```
int transitTime[] =
{
    88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85, //bus 8
    98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89, //bus15
    88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85, //22
    98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89, //23
};

float time[]=
{
    1.00,1.30,2.00,2.30,3.00,3.30,4.00,4.30,5.00,5.30,6.00
};
```

Thanks

Comment: The C++ [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) have many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: I don't understand how the time value selects a column. Also, time is an integer yet you are storing fractional values.

Comment: Hi @NeilKirk, I think theres some problem with my typing of the program. Each column for int transitTime[] represent the transitTime to reach home when leaving at school at different time. For example selecting 1.00 to leave school and finding the largest number at column 1 which is 98

Comment: You you have an array of `int` which you initialize with `double` values. How do you think that will work out?

Comment: If you are learning this, then first you need to know what an array is, how to store data in an array, how to read data in an array and how to iterate through the array from element at position 0 to the last element. So in your for loop you will be traversing the array starting at element at position 0 all the way to the last element. You will also be comparing the current element with the next element for equality. So you should have something like: for(int i = 0; i < time.length; i++){if (time[i] > largest) largest = time[i];} this will loop through the entire array to the last element.

Comment: More useful library algorithms: `std::lowerbound`, `std::upperbound`.  Search the web for examples and read their descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First method: Loop with the no of elements in the row.

```
#include <algorithm>  
#include <vector>
scanf("%d",&number)
int *it = std::find(time,time+11,number);
largest = *it;
for(int *i=it;i<11*4;i = i+11)
{
  if(*i >largest)largest=*i;
}
```

Comment: He wants to select time, from `time` array which are floating values (although OP wrong has used `int` array ). I don't think OP need to enter an index for `time` array

Comment: Hi @lakesh thanks for the help! May i ask how do i fix the error for it=std because its underlined in red. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @lakesh Thanks for the help! How do I fix the error of it as the error now is it is undefine

Comment: the it of it=std @lakesh

Comment: Hi @lakesh Thanks for the help! The = of it-std is now underlined red and the it for for(i=it;) is also underlined in red. How do i fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @lakesh! Thanks for the help buddy! Manage to solve it with your help!! Thanks man!! :)